# Qt DrawLine - change line color dynamically while drawing, without splitting the line

Tags: c++, qt

I am drawing a line in an object derived from QWidget. I can set the pen to draw a line in the color of my choice. What I want to be able to do is change the color of the pen when it's current y coordinate is above a specified value.

One option is simply to split the line I want to draw into two separate halves; split where the y coordinate is above the specified value. While there is nothing wrong with this method, I was hoping that there was a simpler method I could use.

What I want to be able to do is basically extend the drawline function. I want to be able to change the drawing algorithm so that, for each pixel it wants to set the color of, it will check which color to use based on a supplied function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to overload the basic drawing algorithm. I think it be more easy to use a `QGradient` when drawing the line?

Comment: I don't want to use a gradient though. I want to use two solid colors. Is this possible with a QLinearGradient?

Comment: Well i can't test it at the moment, but i thought of overloading the gradient class implementing the behaviour, you want to have, but i can't tell you if this will work.

Comment: I managed to use a QLinearGradient to create the effect by creating points using setColorAt really close together thus creating an instant transition between the colors.

Comment: Hm... but if they are "really close" to each other there will be a minimal color transition between those points. You could try to place them on top of each other, so that you "effectivly" only have three points.

Comment: They were close enough to avoid there being even one pixel of distance between the areas. So you could never see the minute transition. But regardless the system was too slow, so I had to give in and just split all the lines along the transition zones.

Comment: @JonathanPierce How did you ultimately handle the splitting of the lines along the transition?